# openapi-generator Docker command in Windows Terminal GitBash - wrong input path

Tags: docker, docker-volume, openapi-generator

[Here](https://openapi-generator.tech/) it shows this example:

```bash
docker run --rm \
    -v $PWD:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
    -i /local/petstore.yaml \
    -g go \
    -o /local/out/go
```

I'm on Windows.
I'm using GitBash inside Windows Terminal (started as Administrator).
My local directory is *c/Data/Test* and the swagger json file is *test-api.json*.
I created a generate.sh file with:

```bash
here=/c/Data/Test
openapi_file=test_api.json
language=csharp

docker run --rm \
    -v $here:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
    -i /local/$openapi_file \
    -g $language \
    -o /local/out/$language
```

and I get this error:

> [error] The spec file is not found: C:/Program Files/Git/local/core-api-1.0.0-openapi.json
> [error] Check the path of the OpenAPI spec and try again.

**Why is it using "C:/Program Files/Git" ?**

It seems like the *-i /local* parameter is ignored or the volume is not well registered.
I also tried to use *-w $here* but it says the path should be absolute (it is!)
I tried to run the docker interactive to see what the volume contains and maybe to call the generate command manually but that container seems to not be possible to be run in "interactive".
`$ docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli`

**[EDIT]**
I tried again on another PC using the VS Code Terminal (with GitBash) instead of Windows Terminal.
As suggested I tried a different syntax to pass the host path:

- here=d/temp/openapi
- here=d:/temp/openapi
- here=/d:/temp/openapi

Also passing the suggested path directly in the command, without using a variable:

- `-v /d:/temp/openapi:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \`

Aleways got the same error:

> [error] The spec file is not found: C:/Program Files/Git/local/petstore.yml

[image]

Comment: I've published a video to show how to use openapi-generator-cli via Docker on Windows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MuEP01h1XU. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is the issue with `pwd` when using Git-bash.

Try providing the path with this format:

Assuming you want to map the directory in `d:\my-folder\test`

```bash
here=/d:/my-folder/test
openapi_file=petstore.yaml
language=csharp

docker run --rm -v $here:/local \
    openapitools/openapi-generator-cli \
    sh -c 'docker-entrypoint.sh generate -i /local/'$openapi_file' -g '$language' -o /local/output/'
```

Notice the path:

`d:\my-folder\test` changed to `/d:/my-folder/test`

Update, uploaded to Gist:

bash script: https://gist.github.com/Peymanpn/0af8d98b64566a9201f740a97f7d0651

I tested your code and it seemed that the error you were seeing belonged to the second part, when you were passing `-i /local/petstore.yaml`.

Please see the Gist, which I have tested already,
I hope that could help

Comment: No luck. Still same error.

Comment: hey @Alex75, I have replicated the situation,  and could get working results.